# Configuring Oracle XStream

Tags: oracle, xstream

I'm trying to configure Oracle XStream out by official [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/XSTRM/xstrm_xout_config.htm#XSTRM1496)

So, shortly, I'm connecting as sysdba

```
    sqlplus / as sysdba
```

Then executing commands create create CDB user and give him privileges

```
    > CREATE TABLESPACE xstream_tbs DATAFILE '$ORACLE/cdb/orcl/xstream_tbs.dbf' SIZE 25M REUSE AUTOEXTEND ON MAXSIZE UNLIMITED;
    > CREATE USER c##xstrmadmin IDENTIFIED BY password DEFAULT TABLESPACE xstream_tbs   QUOTA UNLIMITED ON xstream_tbs container=all;
    > GRANT CREATE SESSION, SET CONTAINER TO c##xstrmadmin CONTAINER=ALL;
```

After this step I should give permissions to user to use XStream

```
    > BEGIN
        DBMS_XSTREAM_AUTH.GRANT_ADMIN_PRIVILEGE(
          grantee                 => 'c##xstrmadmin',
          privilege_type          => 'CAPTURE',
          grant_select_privileges => TRUE,
          container => 'ALL');
      END;
      /
```

On this stage, I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-44001: invalid schema
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_XSTREAM_AUTH_IVK", line 3383
ORA-06512: at line 1
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_XSTREAM_AUTH_IVK", line 3500
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_XSTREAM_AUTH", line 34
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

Current container is cdb$root

Googling gives actually nothing and I have no idea whats wrong as I'm following DBA documentation.

Comment: I've tried as 'C##XSTRMADMIN' too, but no luck

Answer (score 0):

I guess I found workaround.

If you connect to oracle with

```
> sqlplus /nolog
```

And then connect as sysdba

```
> conn / as sysdba
```

Then all works fine!

If this is only one way to resolve problem with creating permissions then problem is in sqlplus or oracle itself. Sad!

Comment: In my case, even this didn't work! Do you know of any other solution by now, as this question was asked quite a while ago?