# Getting 'ORA-44001: invalid schema' error while granting admin privileges to the XStream admin user in the container Database in Oracle

Tags: oracle, apache-kafka-connect, debezium, oracle-golden-gate

I am trying to create an XStream admin user in the container database following the guide in [Debezium Connector for Oracle](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.0/connectors/oracle.html). I want to stream data from Oracle into Kafka. I created table spaces in both the container database and the pluggable database using the following commands while logged in as sys user and in the container database:

```
CREATE TABLESPACE xstream_adm_tbs DATAFILE '/opt/oracle/oradata/ORCL/xstream_adm_tbs.dbf'
  SIZE 25M REUSE AUTOEXTEND ON MAXSIZE UNLIMITED;
```

Then I created the table space in the pluggable database while logged in as sys user in the pdb database using the following command:

```
CREATE TABLESPACE xstream_adm_tbs DATAFILE '/opt/oracle/oradata/ORCL/ORCLPDB/xstream_adm_tbs.dbf'
  SIZE 25M REUSE AUTOEXTEND ON MAXSIZE UNLIMITED;
```

After that I logged in the container db as sys user and created an XStream Admin user using the following command:

```
CREATE USER c##xstrmadmin IDENTIFIED BY password
  DEFAULT TABLESPACE xstream_adm_tbs
  QUOTA UNLIMITED ON xstream_adm_tbs
  CONTAINER=ALL;
```

I then granted the following privileges to this user:

```
GRANT CREATE SESSION, SET CONTAINER TO c##xstrmadmin CONTAINER=ALL;
```

After that I ran the following command while being in the container db:

```
BEGIN
   DBMS_XSTREAM_AUTH.GRANT_ADMIN_PRIVILEGE(
      grantee                 => 'c##xstrmadmin',
      privilege_type          => 'CAPTURE',
      grant_select_privileges => TRUE,
      container               => 'ALL'
   );
END;
/
```

It threw the following error:

> ORA-44001: invalid schema

I tried everything to the best of my knowledge. Perhaps, I have missed something in the steps above. Any help would be appreciated.

Container Database: ORCL
Pluggable Database: ORCLPDB

Comment: Try to use `c##xstrmadmin` in upper case as grantee.

Comment: Does this _Stack Overflow_ Q&A help? [Configuring Oracle XStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47713909/configuring-oracle-xstream?rq=1)

Comment: @Abra This seems helpful. Let met try.

Comment: @Abra I tried with the link you provided. Still didn't work.

Comment: Which Oracle version are you using?

Comment: @Abra I am using 12c